# Setting selective text to textviews dynamically from a URL

Tags: java, android, xml

I am fetching some texts and images from the xml feed of a website. But those having nested tags, aren't displayed in my app. 
Is there any way I can exclude nested tags from xml format of a website ?

I am having something like written below-

`<description><Some text here... <span class="read-more"><a href="http://some_url_here"></a></span>></description>`

Now I want to fetch only "Some text here..." in my app.
Is there any way I can exclude `<span class="read-more"><a href="http://some_url_here"</a></span>` ?

Comment: You can use some XML parsing library or android XmlPullParser to convert your XML-string to XML structure, then exclude not necessary tags and then convert that structure to string. You can start by reading that article: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much for your help. (y)